# MySQL connection in python 3.X for 64bit

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python

I've built a large program that runs queries on `MySQL` dbs via `python 3.X` scripts. I developed it while working on a 32-bit system, but now am trying to run it on my new 64-bit machine. Thus far I have been unable to find a clear answer on whether or not a module exists for `Python 3.X` that works for `MySQL` in a 64bit environment. When I try to import my module that works fine in 32 bit Windows I get this error:

> "ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application." .

I've inspected the module source and considered changing it up. But before I do that I want to be sure there isn't already a module available.

In a nutshell my questions are:

> 1. Is there any pre-built module for linking MySQL/Python in 64bit available for 3.X
> 2. If not.... Are there any ideas for other workarounds that would allow me to do this short of rewriting the MySQLdb existing module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precompiled Windows 64 bit Python 3.2 binary packages for [oursql](https://launchpad.net/oursql) and [MySQL-python](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/) are available from the page [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) page.